# How can I AJAX-populate groups of form elements in a way that is accessible with PHP?

Tags: php, ajax, forms, append, grouping

I'm working on a form that begins with a search auto-complete (ajax, jQuery UI) field that allows users to select a record that already exists in the database. When a record is chosen, fields in the rest of the form are completed for the user. This works well.

Within the form there is a group of fields that together describe a 'widget.' This is an example of the markup that exists before an auto-complete is fired;

```
<fieldset id="widgets">
    <div id="widget_1">
        <input type="text" name="widgets[0][name]" />
        <input type="text" name="widgets[0][color]" />
        <input type="text" name="widgets[0][shape]" />
        <input type="text" name="widgets[0][size]" />
    </div>
</fieldset>
```

I've structured the `name` attributes in this manner hoping that I'll get a nice structure on the back-end when the form is submitted. This markup exists when the page loads to allow users to add a widget to a record if none currently exist.

I'm imagining that when additional widgets are added the structure will become something like this. I should note that there should always be a group of widget fields empty at the bottom in order for users to add a new widget to an existing record.

```
<fieldset id="widgets">
    <div id="widget_1">
        <input type="text" name="widgets[1][name]" value="Alpha" />
        <input type="text" name="widgets[1][color]" value="Red" />
        <input type="text" name="widgets[1][shape]" value="Triangle" />
        <input type="text" name="widgets[1][size]" value="Large" />
    </div>

    <div id="widget_2">
        <input type="text" name="widgets[2][name]" />
        <input type="text" name="widgets[2][color]" />
        <input type="text" name="widgets[2][shape]" />
        <input type="text" name="widgets[2][size]" />
    </div>

    ...

</fieldset>
```

The auto-complete ajax returns a nice JSON structure that includes an array for every record with all the widgets to parse through.

What's the best way to handle adding grouped widget fields to this structure? Is adding an incrementing `id` to the wrapper a good way for me to keeps tabs on what's-in-which row (or would data-attributes be better)?

I'm just trying to get a better handle on how I should tackle this.

Comment: The answer depends on your access use-cases, do you need to loop through the 4 elements of a row at any given time?

Comment: No, I don't believe I do on the front-end. 

However, for example, say I have a `city` select field in my widget that is dependent on the `state` field selection (which is constructed by the back-end). I supposed I can have javascript simply fill in the next `city` field when the `state` field has a selection, or is it a good idea to have some sort of unique `id` on it's parent container?

Comment: unique id are needed if you need to interact with the element on the client side.